# Able to hitTestObject Stage?

Tags: actionscript-3

Can a MovieClip hitTestObject a Stage, or it need to have a MovieClip BG above the Stage in order run a hitTestObject on a fake stage?

Answer (score 0):

The Stage class extends DisplayObject so you should have the hitTestObject method available